# References for Duality Theory

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, book-recommendation, economics, duality-theorems

I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations for Duality Theory. I've touched on Duality before in various courses but it's coming up quite a lot in my studies at the moment.

I guess what I'm after is more of introduction with everything I need kind of in one place. Maybe a topological viewpoint, but I'm not really sure.

Not that it matters but it comes up a lot in microeconomics, so if anyone had any suggestions in regard to that it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not so sure it is clear what "duality theory" is in this context. You tagged general topology and vector spaces, which makes me think that perhaps you are interested in duals of Banach spaces. In that case, I would recommend looking for a book on functional analysis.

Comment: Okay my apologies I've only ever heard it as "Duality Theory" and I'm not so clear on what it is myself. I guess one of the main definitions I've been hearing is that the dual of a vector space E is the set of all continuous functions mapping E to R. Does that help hone in on what area I'm actually looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is also the kind of dual that I was thinking about. You might be interested in Applied Functional Analysis, 2nd Edition by Jean-Pierre Aubin. I'm not sure if this is a good book as I have personally not read it, but I remember seeing that its motivations were economic. You might want to flip through the table of contents or introduction.

Comment: Great thanks! I'll check it out.